# selenium is not able to identify radiobutton

Tags: selenium

```
driver.get("http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_radio_button.cfm");

List<WebElement> radio_button = driver.findElements(By.name("preferred_color"));

System.out.println(radio_button.get(0).getAttribute("value"));

System.out.println(radio_button.get(0).getAttribute("checked"));

radio_button.get(0).click(); //check the radio button if it is unchecked

System.out.println(radio_button.get(0).getAttribute("checked"));
```

this is the error I am getting :-

> Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353145
>   (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067) on port 29374 Only local
>   connections are allowed. Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 at
>   java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source) at
>   java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source) at test.main(test.java:27)

Comment: this is the error I am getting ...Starting ChromeDriver 2.20.353145 (343b531d31eeb933ec778dbcf7081628a1396067) on port 29374
Only local connections are allowed.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
 at test.main(test.java:27)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your radio buttons are inside an `iframe` with name `result1`, so you need to switch that `iframe` first then go to find radio elements as :-

```
driver.switchTo().frame("result1");
```

Full code :-

```
driver.get("http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_radio_button.cfm");

driver.switchTo().frame("result1");

List<WebElement> radio_buttons = driver.findElements(By.name("preferred_color"));

System.out.println(radio_buttons.size());

if(radio_buttons.size() > 0) {

        WebElement radio_button = radio_buttons.get(0);

        System.out.println(radio_button.getAttribute("value"));

        System.out.println(radio_button.isSelected());

        if(!radio_button.isSelected()) {
          ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()", radio_button); //check the radio button if it is unchecked
       }    
        System.out.println(radio_button.isSelected());
}
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. And this code works but only thing is that it doesn't clicks on the given radio button. so both the isselected is returning false.

Comment: @Drake yes as I see unfortunately `click()` does not work here, So I provided you by using `JavascriptExecutor` to perform click..try with updated answer. it will work..:)

Comment: this now works like a charm, But if you can please explain as to why you have to use javascriptexecutor , i am googling it as well. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @Drake Some time due to designing or other problem selenium click does not work so it that case selenium provides `JavascriptExecutor` where by using this we can directly execute javascript on the page to perform certain action for more info follow this link..https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html

Comment: @Drake If the answer solved your problem, Please accept the answer as solved..http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work..:)

Comment: Got loads of information on  javascriptexecutor. But thanks alot for your help!!!